# how do I properly access the array returned from PDO::FETCH_ASSOC?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to compare if either a user or a password exist in the database before adding the result of the form values to the database. Since there should be a 1:1 relationship to a username and an email with both unique as is traditionally a requirement.

It seems like I am not properly dereferencing the username or password values from the array returned from fetchassoc. Becuase the ifstatement returns a synaxerror regarding []

```
$username = !empty($_POST['username'])  ? trim($_POST['username'])  : null;
$password = !empty($_POST['password'])  ? trim($_POST['password'])  : null;
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND email = ? LIMIT 1");
    $query->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(2, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    //wanting to verifying that neither the username nor the email already exist.

    
    if ($result->['username'] !== $username && $result->['email'] !== $email)
```

{

```
$query = $pdo->prepare ("INSERT INTO users....")
```

}

previously my if statement was

```
if(count((array)$result) == 0)
```

But nothing was being inserted into the database and I don't think it will work if a user has entered the same email but a different username or vice versa.

Comment: `$result->['username']` mixes array and object notation, an array is simply `$result['username']`

Comment: Oh I see my bad, thank you!